# More performant: world canvas with a single button vs raycast a sprite renderer or quad?

Tags: unity

Is it more performant to use N of each/either of this

- world canvas with a single button
- raycast hit a SpriteRenderer/box collider
- raycast hit a quad/box collider

in cases where N may involve instantiating a lot of gameobjects of the above at runtime on mobile.

Comment: This sounds like a question that you can answer by building a test scene for each strategy and profiling the results.

Comment: i wonder if that's already been done though - it seems common so why aren't there best practices etc

Comment: A few factors. For one, game developers usually don't publish their profiling results. So unless you get ucky and someone who's done this exact test sees your question, we'd have to do the same test as you to answer it since there's no published source to consult. Secondly,, performance is highly contingent on other specifics of your game — your target hardware, other processing going on in your scene, whether you're CPU or GPU bound,, etc. And thirdly, all that changes every few months when new versions or new phones release. Testing is the best way to get a proven answer for your needs, now.